# C# + ISO8553: генерация MAC

Tags: c#, стандарт, iso

**Добрый день!**

Сейчас пишу реализацию протокола ISO8553, а конкретнее - установка / смена PIN'а карты. Вопрос по полю 64: как мне объяснили в  процессинговом центре, **MAC (Message Authentication Code)** мы должны генерировать сами, а алгоритм его шифрования дать не смогли(не захотели).

**Вопрос:**

Подскажите пожалуйста алгоритм шифрования  это поля, может кто видел где его реализацию?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сначала это почитайте: [Коды проверки подлинности сообщений, хэши и подписи (приложения среды выполнения Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh464996.aspx)

[MacAlgorithmProvider class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.security.cryptography.core.macalgorithmprovider.aspx)

```
using Windows.Security.Cryptography;
using Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;

namespace SampleMacAlgorithmProvider
{
    sealed partial class MacAlgProviderApp : Application
    {
        public MacAlgProviderApp()
        {
            // Initialize the application.
            this.InitializeComponent();

            // Initialize the hashing process.
            String strMsg = "This is a message to be authenticated";
            String strAlgName = MacAlgorithmNames.HmacSha384;
            IBuffer buffMsg;
            CryptographicKey hmacKey;
            IBuffer buffHMAC;

            // Create a hashed message authentication code (HMAC)
            this.CreateHMAC(
                strMsg,
                strAlgName,
                out buffMsg,
                out hmacKey,
                out buffHMAC);

            // Verify the HMAC.
            this.VerifyHMAC(
                buffMsg,
                hmacKey,
                buffHMAC);
        }

        void CreateHMAC(
            String strMsg,
            String strAlgName,
            out IBuffer buffMsg,
            out CryptographicKey hmacKey,
            out IBuffer buffHMAC)
        {
            // Create a MacAlgorithmProvider object for the specified algorithm.
            MacAlgorithmProvider objMacProv = MacAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(strAlgName);

            // Demonstrate how to retrieve the name of the algorithm used.
            String strNameUsed = objMacProv.AlgorithmName;

            // Create a buffer that contains the message to be signed.
            BinaryStringEncoding encoding = BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8;
            buffMsg = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(strMsg, encoding);

            // Create a key to be signed with the message.
            IBuffer buffKeyMaterial = CryptographicBuffer.GenerateRandom(objMacProv.MacLength);
            hmacKey = objMacProv.CreateKey(buffKeyMaterial);

            // Sign the key and message together.
            buffHMAC = CryptographicEngine.Sign(hmacKey, buffMsg);

            // Verify that the HMAC length is correct for the selected algorithm
            if (buffHMAC.Length != objMacProv.MacLength)
            {
                throw new Exception("Error computing digest");
            }
         }

        public void VerifyHMAC(
            IBuffer buffMsg,
            CryptographicKey hmacKey,
            IBuffer buffHMAC)
        {
            // The input key must be securely shared between the sender of the HMAC and 
            // the recipient. The recipient uses the CryptographicEngine.VerifySignature() 
            // method as follows to verify that the message has not been altered in transit.
            Boolean IsAuthenticated = CryptographicEngine.VerifySignature(hmacKey, buffMsg, buffHMAC);
            if (!IsAuthenticated)
            {
                throw new Exception("The message cannot be verified.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Здесь пример с реализацией класса сообщения по ISO8583: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/377446/BIM-ISO8583

Comment: Вопрос - делаю как в примере, ругается в строках "uising " (напр. Windows.Security.Cryptography;)  на "Windows".Я в ссылках проекта посмотрел, добавить его там не получилось. как можно это исправить?

Comment: версию ОС надо проверить. посмотрите требования: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.aspx

Comment: Если вам нужно для предыдущей платформы, то посмотрите решение на .NET 4.5 с использованием System.Security.Cryptography: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha1(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: вы правы - винда 7 не поддерживается